# Issue with Updating data in Cassandra using Java

Tags: java, cassandra

My table structure in Cassandra:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
   id text,
   location text,
   status text,
   type text,
   duration double,
   threshold double,
   timestamp timestamp,
   segment text,
   PRIMARY KEY (id, location, timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (location ASC, timestamp ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

I am inserting data into this table using `Java`, then after some calculations trying to update same row. The process is insert-update then insert-update......... Here the problem is when I am trying to update using `java` i.e `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Update` first record updating successfully but it is storing `null` values for non-updated fields also, but when I update 2nd time inserted record it is updating only the fields which have to be updated without effecting non-updated fields.

Here is my insert and update codes

```
String names[] = {
        "id ",
        "location",
        "status",
        "type",
        "duration",
        "threshold",
        "timestamp",
        "segment"
};

Object values[] = {
        obj.getId(),
        obj.getLocation(),
        obj.getStatus(),
        obj.gettype(),
        obj.getDuration(),
        obj.getThreshold(),
        obj.getTimestamp(),
        obj.getSegment(),
};

try{
    Insert insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("test");
    insert.values( names, values );
    return session.execute( insert ).wasApplied();
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    logger.error( "Exception while inserting ", ex );
    return false;
}
```

Update method as follows

```
try {
    Update update = QueryBuilder.update("test");

    update.with( QueryBuilder.set("status", obj.getStatus() ) );
    update.with( QueryBuilder.set("type", obj.getType() ) );

    update.where( QueryBuilder.eq("id", obj.getId()) )
        .and( QueryBuilder.eq("location", obj.getLocation() ) )
        .and( QueryBuilder.eq("timestamp", obj.getTimestamp() ) );

    return session.execute( update ).wasApplied();
} catch( Exception ex ) {
    logger.error( "Exception while updating", ex );
    return false;
}
```

When I run the update method first time it is storing `status` and `type` values as expected but making other `duration`, `threshold` and `segment` as `null`. After inserting another `row` then again run `update` query , this time is updating `status` and `type` without effecting other fields i.e `duration`, `threshold` and `segment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.execute( update.setForceNoValues(false) ).wasApplied()` will help

Comment: here is useful information for similar situation if you use mapper: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/object_mapper/using/

basically there is 'SaveNullFields' option.